# Arithmetic with strings that contain numbers

Tags: perl

What is the Perlish way to deal with arithmetic with strings that contain numbers?

Example: Say I'm dealing with font sizes that are represented with a string like -> "120px". I know the values of font sizes will always be formatted with number characters followed by non-number characters and I know that Perl will truncate any trailing characters of a string in arithmetic so could I do something like the following(with appropriate comments)?

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;

use constant FONT_UNIT => 4; 

my $font_size = "120px";

STDOUT->print("${font_size}\n");

$font_size = do {no warnings; $font_size + FONT_UNIT}."px";

STDOUT->print("${font_size}\n");

exit (0);
```

I ask because this feature of the language really works here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your approach seems ok. You can also use substitution with evaluation:

```
$font_size =~ s/([0-9]+)/$1 + FONT_UNIT/e;
```

Or, if you need clarity, just extract the number, change it, and glue the parts back:

```
my ($size, $unit) = $font_size =~ /([0-9]+)(.*)/;
$size += FONT_UNIT;
STDOUT->say("$size$unit");
```

Answer (score 2):

The only two suggestions I'd make would be to be more precise about which warnings you're turning off and to use a slightly larger naked code block to make it more readable.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;

use constant FONT_UNIT => 4; 

my $font_size = "120px";

STDOUT->print("${font_size}\n");

{
  no warnings 'numeric';

  $font_size = $font_size + FONT_UNIT . "px";
}

STDOUT->print("${font_size}\n");

exit (0);
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the Perlish way to deal with arithmetic with strings that contain numbers?

Leading and trailing whitespace is ignored (without generating a warning).

`inf`, `infinity`, `nan`, case insensitive, after stripping whitespace, and with optional leading + or -, are treated as those special numbers (without generating a warning).

`0 but true` (no extra whitespace allowed) is treated as the number 0 (without generating a warning).

Any leading thing that looks like an integer or decimal number with an optional following e or E and optionally signed exponent is treated as that number (to the extent it can be represented in a numeric type).  If any non-whitespace characters remain afterwards, an "isn't numeric" warning is generated.